# Databound ContentControl Transition animation?

Tags: wpf, animation

I have a ContentControl that is databound using this syntax:

```
<ContentControl  Content="{Binding Path=View}"></ContentControl>
```

I replace the View using commands and was wondering if it was possible to use an animation when this property was changed, e.g. changed from one UserControl to another?

Looking forward to hear from you.

Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 3):

[PixelLab](http://thinkpixellab.com/) provide an open source [Bag of Tricks](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot) which contains a set of transitions which can be use to animate changing the content of a control, eg when switching between views.

You can replace the `ContentControl` with the `TransitionPresenter`

```
<lib:TransitionPresenter Transition="{StaticResource FadeTransition}" Content="{Binding View}" />
```

Comment: Does there exist a way to do this without that 'bag of tricks'? I wish to keep the application as light-weight as possible...

Comment: It's all open source so you can just [pull out the files](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot/blob/master/Wpf/Transitions/TransitionPresenter.cs) you need

Comment: I thank you for the useful link. I was unable to make it work however. I created a static resource: <lib:FadeTransition x:Key="FadeTrans" Duration="0:0:1"/> and replaced my ContentControl like you wrote. It does not fade, but changes immediately. <lib:TransitionPresenter Transition="{StaticResource FadeTrans}" Content="{Binding Path=View}"/>

Comment: I'm not following the design... I'm trying to merge the transition into a mvvm design pattern using commands and workspaces but no luck. Can anybody elaborate on Tom's suggestion?

Comment: Could you provide additional usage details? There is no documentation to be found anywhere on the internet for this library!  For example, what's the xmlns for this library ('lib:' in your answer)?